# React Form Input with initial text value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/) input components and would like an initial value for the input component, but I cannot see how to do this. Using `defaultValue` does not put a physical text into the input component, which is what I am trying to do. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my component:

```
    <InputGroup>
      <FormControl
        aria-label="Default"
        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
        value = {this.state.name}
        onChange={(event)=>{
                    this.setState({
                       name:event.target.value
                    });
                 }}
        readOnly={ isReadOnly }
        defaultValue={this.state.name}     // ---> This is what should make the text read the pre-existing name

      />
    </InputGroup>
```

Comment: Looking at React Bootstrap examples, this seems fine.. post your whole component file code including state

Comment: Seems fine can you create stackblitz demo to reproduce?

Comment: Actually, you have no `type` assigned to this component.. what is it, a text field?

Comment: Yep, it's a text field @AshleyBrown

Comment: Are you able to set a value by hard coding it rather than relying on the state value as a test?

Comment: Ok, so figured out the problem. Firstly, I could not get it to work by hard-coding a default value, but I figured out now that the default value was overridden immediately anyways by the state variable/property to which the input field's normal value was set to (initialized to an empty string). I did not bind the data retrieval from the database, so the data wasn't coming in, but the initial value was an empty string, which took precedence over the default value for the input field.

Comment: I appreciate the help though @AshleyBrown

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Post your comment as an answer to this question so that you may accept your own answer within a few days to resolve this issue - happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It gets its value from `state.name` so instead you should define default state on your component that holds the control.

For example in the constructor:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        name: 'default value',
    }
}
```

If your form is to be pre-populated with existing server-side data, you might want to set it as the component loads (after a call to the backend). In which case you could hook into the `componentDidMount` method. Read more about component life cycle methods here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle